# Piecewise linear spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes, piecewise-continuity

Define a piecewise linear sphere to be a simplicial complex that admits a subdivision, which is simplicially isomorphic to a subdivision of the boundary of a simplex.

What's the current state of the theory of piecewise linear spheres? In particular, I'm interested in

1. The classification of all piecewise linear spheres, up to PL-isomorphisms.

Denote the space of piecewise linear spheres of dimension $n$ by $T_n$. Given a PL sphere $S$ of dimension $n$ and a vertex $v \in S$. The link of $v$ in $S$ is another PL sphere $s$, which I call local spheres. Let $C(S)$ be the subset (of $T_{n-1}$) that consists of possible local spheres $s$.

2. Is $C(S) = C(S')$, provided that $S$ and $S'$ are isomorphic?

Comment: What do you mean by a PL sphere? Do you mean a closed PL-manifold homotopy-equivalent to the standard sphere? Then the classification in dimensions $\ne 4$ is that $T_n$ is a singleton. Dimension 4 is a major open problem (if homeomorphism implies PL isomorphism). Q2 has tautologically positive answer, maybe you meant to ask a different question.

Comment: Thank you @MoisheKohan, I was not aware of the confusion. I mean a closed PL-manifold homeomorphic to the standard sphere.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture#Status

Comment: That's .. astonishing. Sorry to be equivocal.. but I don't really know PL theory. How about this: define a PL sphere to be a simplicial complex that admits a subdivision that is simplicially isomorphic to a subdivision of the boundary of a simplex.

Comment: This would be quite boring, they are all PL equivalent, by definition.